# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android

Im trying to build an app that basically plays an mp4 file in the raw resource directory when a button is pressed or after matching from a speech recognizer. The app builds successfully and runs fine when there is a small amount of video files (no more than 50mb). This problem occurs when I add more video files (the total size reaches around 4.5gb). I think the problem is because of the size of the resource files

This is the full error log while building:

Task :app:processDebugResources
AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #0 Failed to shutdown within timeout
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #0: Failed to shut down within 30 seconds. Forcing shutdown
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:224)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.shutDown(Aapt2Daemon.kt:148)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:183)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError$default(Aapt2Daemon.kt:168)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:128)
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:175)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnableKt.processResources(Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable.kt:80)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:856)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.run(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:737)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:348)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows Daemon #0: Link timed out, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.